# How to show the small component is likely to be a tree in a random graph

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

I was just looking a book and the book said For a graph in supercritical regime (np > 1). For the small component (size s) not a part of giant component, it is a tree (which means the number of edges in the small component is s - 1). So, anyone who can tell me how to prove it?

Thanks

Comment: The "supercritical regime" is not the same as $np > 1$. For example, if $p = \frac1n + \frac1{n^2}$, we are still within the critical window and there is no giant component.

Answer (score 1):

This is false. You can say that the small components are *simple* meaning that they contain at most one cycle, but you cannot guarantee that they are all trees.

For instance, let's consider $p = \frac cn$ (for any positive real $c$, whether it is bigger than $1$ or not) and count the components which are triangles. Let $X$ be the number of such components.

The probability that three given vertices induce a triangle component is $p^3 (1-p)^{3(n-3)} \sim p^3 e^{-3np} = p^3 e^{-3c}$ and since there are $\binom n3 \sim \frac{n^3}{6}$ ways to choose three vertices, we have (multiplying these together) $\mathbb E[X] \sim \frac{c^3}{6} e^{-3c}$.

To compute $\mathbb E[X^2]$, we count the number of ordered pairs of triangle components. There are $X$ pairs in which a component is paired with itself. As for pairs of two distinct components, there are $\binom n3 \binom{n-3}3 \sim \frac{n^6}{36}$ ways to choose their vertices, and the probability is $p^6 (1-p)^{6(n-6)+9} \sim p^6 e^{-6c}$ that any given choice induces two triangle components, so in expectation (by multiplying these together) there are $\frac{c^6}{36} e^{-6c}$ such pairs. Therefore $\mathbb E[X^2] \sim \frac{c^3}{6}e^{-3c} + \frac{c^6}{36} e^{-6c}$, and $\mathrm{Var}[X] \sim \frac{c^3}{6}e^{-3c}$.

Now apply the one-sided Chebyshev's inequality to conclude that
$$
   \Pr[X = 0] \le \frac{\mathrm{Var}[X]}{\mathbb E[X^2]} \sim \frac{\frac{c^3}{6}e^{-3c}}{\frac{c^3}{6}e^{-3c} + \frac{c^6}{36} e^{-6c}} = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{c^3}{6}e^{-3c}}.
$$
For any constant $c>0$, this is bounded away from $1$ as $n \to \infty$, and so there is a constant positive probability of finding triangle components.

(These are only one example of non-tree small components; they are just the easiest to analyze.)

Answer (score -1):

If you have an Erdős–Rényi random graph, one way to show this is true in expectation is to start with a tree and calculate the expected number of *extra* edge creating loops.

Consider an Erdős–Rényi random graph with $n$ vertices and probability $p$ of an edge between any pairs of vertices.

The expected degree, per vertex is given by

\begin{align*}
d = \mathbb{E}[k] = \mathbb{E}[\frac{2m}{n}] = \frac{2\mathbb{E}[m]}{n} = \frac{2}{n}{n \choose 2}p = \left(n-1\right)p
\end{align*}

This allows us to rewrite the probability parameter in terms of the expected degree as
\begin{align*}
p = \frac{d}{n-1}
\end{align*}

Now suppose you are looking at small component that is a tree. If the small component contains $n_s$ vertices, then it must contain exactly $m_s = n_s -1$ edges. Now the we may ask, what is the expected number of *extra* edges one would observe?

There are ${n_s \choose 2}$ ways one could place an edge, and there are $n_s -1$ existing edges in the component, so the expected number of extra edges will simply be:
\begin{align*}
m_{\text{extra}}=\frac{(n_s-1)(n_s-2)}{2}\left(\frac{d}{n-1}\right)
\end{align*}

So, in the limit of $n \rightarrow \infty$, (including $np>1$), the expected number of loop creating edges tends to $0$ and the component is a tree.

Comment: What you're missing is that there are many small components (when, say, $p = \frac cn$). You're picking a particular component and showing that it's unlikely to have any extra edges: an $O(\frac1n)$ chance. But because there are $O(n)$ small components, we expect some of them to hit on that $O(\frac1n)$ chance anyway, and then we get small components that are not trees.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, what is the expected number of cyclic small components for an ER-graph as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: When $p = \frac cn$ for constant $c>1$, it's some positive constant depending on $c$. Working out the details seems messy; this is why I stuck to just triangle components in my answer. What we usually say is that there are no small *complex* components in this range: components with $k$ vertices and more than $k$ edges. (That's similar to the argument you gave, except we get a probability of $O(\frac1{n^2})$, which beats the $O(n)$ total number of small components.) With high probability, all small components have at most one cycle - and most of them have none.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, I'm not sure that I fully understand your triangle model. What is the _expected_ degree of a vertex in a _small_ component of such a mode?

Comment: When $p = \frac c{n-1}$, the expected degree of an *arbitrary* vertex is $c$. If you want to condition on a vertex being in a small component, that's harder to describe. For $c<1$, the expected degree conditional on being in a small component is still $c + o(1)$, because whp all components are small. For $c>1$, it's well-known that the small components have the same asymptotic distribution as they do for $p = \frac x{n-1}$ where $c e^{-c} = x e^{-x}$ and $x<1$, so the expected degree conditional on being in a small component is $x + o(1)$. ...Why do you ask?